# Spring Boot upgrade to 1.5.4 from 1.5.3 with custom validation config startup failed

Tags: java, spring

When 1.5.3 worked well.
But upgraded to 1.5.4 started failed...

> exception: 2017-06-19 22:41:13,400:ERROR
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry
>   main (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:581) - Destroy method on bean
>   with name
>   'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
>   threw an exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before
>   multicasting events via the context:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3a45c42a:
>   startup date [Mon Jun 19 22:41:11 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
>   [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:556)
>   [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   bing.AuthorityApplication.main(AuthorityApplication.java:40)
>   [classes/:?] 2017-06-19 22:41:13,407:ERROR
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry
>   main (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:581) - Destroy method on bean
>   with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor'
>   threw an exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before
>   multicasting events via the context:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3a45c42a:
>   startup date [Mon Jun 19 22:41:11 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
>   [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:556)
>   [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   bing.AuthorityApplication.main(AuthorityApplication.java:40)
>   [classes/:?] 2017-06-19 22:41:13,409:ERROR
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry
>   main (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:581) - Destroy method on bean
>   with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory'
>   threw an exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before
>   multicasting events via the context:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3a45c42a:
>   startup date [Mon Jun 19 22:41:11 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
>   [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:556)
>   [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]     at
>   bing.AuthorityApplication.main(AuthorityApplication.java:40)
>   [classes/:?] 2017-06-19 22:41:13,422:INFO
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer
>   main (AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer.java:101) -
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2017-06-19
>   22:41:13,663:ERROR
>   org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter
>   main (LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter.java:42) -
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 1 of method methodValidationPostProcessor in
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration
>   required a bean of type 'javax.validation.Validator' that could not be
>   found.
>     - Bean method 'defaultValidator' in 'ValidationAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types:
>   javax.validation.Validator; SearchStrategy: all) found bean
>   'mvcValidator'
>
> Action:
>
> Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type
>   'javax.validation.Validator' in your configuration.

this is my custom validation config, integrated messagesource with jsr303

```
@Configuration
public class ValidationMessageConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean mvcValidator(MessageSource messageSource) {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        factory.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details, and format your output, using the code formatting button. However, as your question currently stands, you can not format the output as there is more code than actual description of the issues that you have. I tried to format it myself and I was unable to submit the proposed edit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how/why it worked with 1.5.3 but you are supposed to configure the default `Validator` by returning one from the `@Bean` annotated method. Rewrite like this:

```
@Bean
public Validator mvcValidator(MessageSource messageSource) {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    factory.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, but it not work. And the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and resolved the issue. Rewrite your configuration like this.

```
@Configuration
public class ValidationMessageConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        factory.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return factory;
    }
}
```